# error build: There is no XCFramework found at '/Users/hirendudhat/Desktop/Raj/YoutSocial/ios/Carthage/Build/PINCache.xcframework'

Tags: react-native

[image]

I am running this project in xcode that time some xcode version error is coming and try to run in xcode then comming above image error so how to solve this error ?

I an trying to delete pod, pod.lock and xcworkspace file then reinstall pod file.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your pods file, [PINCache](https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache) might not have some of the files which is required to run, so try to go to the GitHub, containing [PINCache](https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache) pod and copied the missing files. This might solves the issue.